# __del__ when using __deepcopy__

Tags: python-3.x

I'm curious about the use of Python classes `__del__` method when implementing a custom `__deepcopy__`:

Example:

```
class Node():
    [...]

class List():

    __init__(self):
      [...]

    __deepcopy__(self, list, memo):
        # create new empty list
        # deepcopy the nodes
        # return the new list
        # set some class attribute to ensure it was created using deepcopy

    __del__:
        # If the class has deepcopy attribute, delete all nodes that were deep copied
        # Set the deep copy attribute to none

list1 = List()
list2 = deepcopy(list1)
del list2
```

Do I have to write `__del__` method on `class List`? Most implementations I have seen do not implement the `__del__` method when using a custom `__deepcopy__`. How is the memory allocated using deepcopy released ?

Comment: "How is the memory ... released ?" -> by reference counting and garbage collecting

Comment: `__del__` *does not release memory*. Python != C++. Python is a memory managed language

Comment: So no, you probably don't need to write a `__del__` method in Python, certainly not here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I will call del(node) in `__del__`, should that not reduce the reference count ? In turn enabling the garbage collector to reclaim memory. That should reduce the memory footprint of my code. I think you were correct when you guessed that this question was motivated by a similar procedure in C++

Comment: There is almost certainly no good reason to use `del node` in `__del__`. Let me put it this way, I've used python professionally for the last 4 years and I've written maybe *one* `__del__` method. That was later refactored into a context manager. `__del__` is *not for managing memory*.